# Mouse movements too fast for `mouseMoveEvent()`

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

The following Python 3 resp. UI XML code shows 4 `QProgessBar` for each mouse direction (labeled X+, X-, Y+, Y-).

Fast mouse movements (in circles) will make the 4 `QProgessBar` move up to 99% and then some of the `QProgessBar` take a break until the mouse movements are slowed down to finally reach 100%.

1. What's the reason for this behavior ?
2. How can the code be fixed so that no `QProgessBar` takes a break at 99% ?

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)
        self.showMaximized()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.centralWidget().setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)

        self._old_x = QCursor.pos().x()
        self._old_y = QCursor.pos().y()

    def _update_bar(self, progress_bar, delta):
        current_value = progress_bar.value()
        new_value = current_value + delta
        progress_bar.setValue(new_value)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        new_x = event.x()
        new_y = event.y()

        if new_x > self._old_x:
            self._update_bar(self.progressBar_x_plus, new_x - self._old_x)
        if new_x < self._old_x:
            self._update_bar(self.progressBar_x_minus, self._old_x - new_x)

        if new_y > self._old_y:
            self._update_bar(self.progressBar_y_plus, new_y - self._old_y)
        if new_y < self._old_y:
            self._update_bar(self.progressBar_y_minus, self._old_y - new_y)

        self._old_x = new_x
        self._old_y = new_y


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Mouse Pointer</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_x_plus">
        <property name="text">
         <string>X+</string>
        </property>
        <property name="alignment">
         <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progressBar_x_plus">
        <property name="maximum">
         <number>1000</number>
        </property>
        <property name="value">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_x_minus">
        <property name="text">
         <string>X-</string>
        </property>
        <property name="alignment">
         <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1">
       <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progressBar_x_minus">
        <property name="maximum">
         <number>1000</number>
        </property>
        <property name="value">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_y_plus">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Y+</string>
        </property>
        <property name="alignment">
         <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="1">
       <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progressBar_y_plus">
        <property name="maximum">
         <number>1000</number>
        </property>
        <property name="value">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_y_minus">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Y-</string>
        </property>
        <property name="alignment">
         <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="1">
       <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progressBar_y_minus">
        <property name="maximum">
         <number>1000</number>
        </property>
        <property name="value">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.What's the reason for this behavior ?**

Please write `print(self._old_x, new_x)` and see the result.

In my case, the part of results like this.

```
681 673
673 666
666 660
660 660
660 660
660 661
661 670
670 681
681 693
693 708
708 732
732 750
750 779
```

you can see the same position between `self._old_x` and `new_x`.
and you can also see `self._old_x` is more than `new_x` in the result.

**Why does the same position come?**

It is easy to say... `event.pos()` is `QCursor.pos()`.
But you call `event.x()` and `event.y()` at the first line in `mouseMoveEvent()`.

Between `event.x()`, `event.y()` calling and `new_x`, `new_y` updating, there are a very slight time.So there is no time for moving 1 sometimes.
This is also a reason but it is not core.

And please write `print(progress_bar.objectName(), new_value)` in `_update_bar`

```
progressBar_y_plus 394
progressBar_x_minus 368
progressBar_y_plus 400
progressBar_x_minus 372
progressBar_y_plus 405
progressBar_x_minus 375
progressBar_y_plus 409
progressBar_x_minus 378
progressBar_y_plus 412
progressBar_x_minus 381
progressBar_y_plus 415
progressBar_x_minus 383
progressBar_y_plus 418
progressBar_x_minus 387
progressBar_y_plus 424
progressBar_x_minus 389
progressBar_y_plus 427
progressBar_x_minus 394
progressBar_y_plus 431
progressBar_x_minus 397
progressBar_y_plus 434
progressBar_x_minus 400
progressBar_y_plus 438
progressBar_x_minus 404
progressBar_y_plus 443
progressBar_x_minus 409
progressBar_y_plus 449
progressBar_x_minus 414
progressBar_y_plus 454
progressBar_x_minus 419
progressBar_y_plus 458
progressBar_x_minus 423
progressBar_y_plus 463
progressBar_x_minus 428
progressBar_y_plus 468
progressBar_x_minus 436
progressBar_y_plus 476
progressBar_x_minus 440
progressBar_y_plus 479
progressBar_x_minus 448
progressBar_y_plus 484
progressBar_x_minus 456
progressBar_y_plus 489
progressBar_x_minus 462
progressBar_y_plus 493
progressBar_x_minus 467
progressBar_y_plus 495
progressBar_x_minus 475
progressBar_y_plus 497
progressBar_x_minus 482
progressBar_y_plus 500
progressBar_x_minus 489
progressBar_x_minus 503
progressBar_y_plus 504
progressBar_x_minus 515
progressBar_x_minus 529
progressBar_x_minus 541
progressBar_x_minus 559
progressBar_x_minus 575
progressBar_x_minus 598
progressBar_x_minus 619
progressBar_x_minus 631
progressBar_x_minus 657
progressBar_x_minus 675
progressBar_x_minus 679
progressBar_x_minus 682
progressBar_x_minus 707
progressBar_y_minus 807
progressBar_x_minus 742
progressBar_y_minus 818
progressBar_x_minus 767
progressBar_y_minus 819
progressBar_x_minus 799
progressBar_x_minus 814
progressBar_x_minus 825
progressBar_y_minus 822
progressBar_x_minus 842
progressBar_y_minus 823
progressBar_x_minus 857
progressBar_y_minus 825
progressBar_x_minus 863
progressBar_y_minus 826
progressBar_x_minus 877
progressBar_y_minus 831
progressBar_x_minus 892
progressBar_x_minus 907
progressBar_x_minus 918
progressBar_y_minus 835
progressBar_x_minus 928
progressBar_x_minus 931
progressBar_x_minus 936
progressBar_x_minus 940
progressBar_x_minus 945
progressBar_x_minus 949
progressBar_x_minus 952
progressBar_x_minus 956
progressBar_x_minus 959
progressBar_x_minus 963
progressBar_x_minus 970
progressBar_x_minus 975
progressBar_x_minus 980
progressBar_x_minus 987
progressBar_x_minus 992
progressBar_x_minus 998
progressBar_x_minus 1002
progressBar_x_minus 1001
progressBar_x_minus 1000
progressBar_x_minus 1004
progressBar_x_minus 1003
progressBar_x_minus 1001
progressBar_x_minus 1001
progressBar_x_minus 1001
progressBar_x_minus 1001
progressBar_x_plus 475
progressBar_x_plus 482
progressBar_x_plus 496
progressBar_x_plus 509
progressBar_x_plus 524
progressBar_x_plus 548
progressBar_x_plus 579
progressBar_x_plus 614
progressBar_x_plus 673
progressBar_x_plus 718
progressBar_x_plus 756
progressBar_x_plus 788
progressBar_x_plus 826
progressBar_x_plus 848
progressBar_y_minus 836
progressBar_x_plus 898
progressBar_y_plus 507
progressBar_x_plus 940
progressBar_x_plus 978
progressBar_x_plus 993
progressBar_x_plus 1014
progressBar_x_plus 1014
progressBar_x_plus 1010
progressBar_x_plus 1016
progressBar_x_plus 1015
progressBar_y_plus 509
progressBar_x_plus 1018
progressBar_x_plus 1012
progressBar_x_plus 1011
progressBar_x_plus 1000
progressBar_x_plus 1012
progressBar_x_plus 1019
progressBar_x_plus 1015
progressBar_x_plus 1012
progressBar_x_plus 1015
progressBar_x_plus 1019
progressBar_x_plus 1015
progressBar_x_plus 1015
progressBar_x_plus 1012
progressBar_x_plus 1014
progressBar_x_plus 1005
progressBar_x_plus 1003
progressBar_x_plus 1009
progressBar_y_minus 839
progressBar_x_plus 1008
progressBar_y_minus 841
progressBar_x_plus 1012
progressBar_y_minus 844
progressBar_x_plus 1011
progressBar_y_minus 848
progressBar_x_plus 1006
progressBar_y_minus 851
progressBar_x_plus 1007
progressBar_y_minus 855
progressBar_x_plus 1006
progressBar_y_minus 860
progressBar_x_plus 1007
progressBar_y_minus 865
progressBar_x_plus 1001
progressBar_y_minus 866
progressBar_x_plus 1001
progressBar_x_plus 1004
progressBar_y_minus 872
progressBar_x_plus 1005
progressBar_y_minus 881
progressBar_x_plus 1005
progressBar_y_minus 889
progressBar_x_plus 1007
progressBar_y_minus 898
progressBar_x_plus 1004
progressBar_y_minus 907
progressBar_x_plus 1005
progressBar_y_minus 917
progressBar_x_plus 1005
progressBar_y_minus 931
progressBar_x_plus 1004
progressBar_y_minus 941
progressBar_x_plus 1004
progressBar_y_minus 952
progressBar_x_plus 1005
progressBar_y_minus 965
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_y_minus 977
progressBar_x_plus 1001
progressBar_y_minus 991
progressBar_x_plus 1001
progressBar_y_minus 1004
progressBar_y_minus 1005
progressBar_x_plus 1003
progressBar_y_minus 1001
progressBar_y_minus 1007
progressBar_y_minus 1004
progressBar_y_minus 1005
progressBar_y_minus 1005
progressBar_x_minus 1003
progressBar_y_minus 1001
progressBar_x_minus 1004
progressBar_y_minus 1004
progressBar_y_minus 996
progressBar_x_minus 1006
progressBar_y_minus 1007
progressBar_x_minus 1008
progressBar_y_minus 1007
progressBar_x_minus 1007
progressBar_y_minus 1007
progressBar_x_minus 1008
progressBar_y_minus 1009
progressBar_x_minus 1009
progressBar_y_minus 1007
progressBar_x_minus 1005
progressBar_y_minus 1005
progressBar_x_minus 1010
progressBar_y_minus 1006
progressBar_x_minus 1007
progressBar_y_minus 1004
progressBar_x_minus 1010
progressBar_y_minus 1004
progressBar_x_minus 1008
progressBar_y_minus 1001
progressBar_x_minus 1008
progressBar_y_minus 1005
progressBar_x_minus 1013
progressBar_y_minus 1005
progressBar_x_minus 1012
progressBar_y_minus 1003
progressBar_x_minus 1023
progressBar_y_minus 1004
progressBar_x_minus 1013
progressBar_y_minus 1003
progressBar_x_minus 1016
progressBar_y_minus 1003
progressBar_x_minus 1015
progressBar_y_minus 1003
progressBar_x_minus 1014
progressBar_y_minus 1002
progressBar_x_minus 1018
progressBar_y_minus 1000
progressBar_x_minus 1015
progressBar_y_minus 1005
progressBar_x_minus 1009
progressBar_y_minus 1002
progressBar_x_minus 1018
progressBar_y_minus 1003
progressBar_x_minus 1015
progressBar_y_minus 1003
progressBar_x_minus 1014
progressBar_y_minus 1001
progressBar_x_minus 1015
progressBar_y_minus 1005
progressBar_x_minus 1009
progressBar_x_minus 1012
progressBar_y_minus 1001
progressBar_x_minus 1012
progressBar_x_minus 1014
progressBar_x_minus 1008
progressBar_x_minus 1014
progressBar_x_minus 1012
progressBar_x_minus 1015
progressBar_x_minus 1014
progressBar_x_minus 1012
progressBar_x_minus 1013
progressBar_x_minus 1014
progressBar_y_plus 512
progressBar_x_minus 1014
progressBar_y_plus 515
progressBar_x_minus 1014
progressBar_y_plus 519
progressBar_x_minus 1018
progressBar_y_plus 525
progressBar_x_minus 1009
progressBar_y_plus 528
progressBar_x_minus 1012
progressBar_y_plus 532
progressBar_x_minus 1013
progressBar_y_plus 536
progressBar_x_minus 1014
progressBar_y_plus 540
progressBar_x_minus 1010
progressBar_y_plus 546
progressBar_x_minus 1015
progressBar_y_plus 553
progressBar_x_minus 1012
progressBar_y_plus 558
progressBar_x_minus 1010
progressBar_y_plus 565
progressBar_x_minus 1012
progressBar_y_plus 572
progressBar_x_minus 1013
progressBar_y_plus 580
progressBar_x_minus 1008
progressBar_y_plus 586
progressBar_x_minus 1012
progressBar_y_plus 596
progressBar_x_minus 1010
progressBar_y_plus 604
progressBar_x_minus 1009
progressBar_y_plus 612
progressBar_x_minus 1010
progressBar_y_plus 623
progressBar_x_minus 1006
progressBar_y_plus 629
progressBar_x_minus 1007
progressBar_y_plus 637
progressBar_x_minus 1005
progressBar_y_plus 648
progressBar_x_minus 1003
progressBar_y_plus 655
progressBar_x_minus 1002
progressBar_y_plus 663
progressBar_x_minus 1003
progressBar_y_plus 673
progressBar_x_minus 1004
progressBar_y_plus 684
progressBar_x_minus 1001
progressBar_y_plus 693
progressBar_y_plus 702
progressBar_y_plus 712
progressBar_y_plus 713
progressBar_y_plus 718
progressBar_y_plus 724
progressBar_x_plus 1001
progressBar_y_plus 734
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_y_plus 743
progressBar_y_plus 757
progressBar_y_plus 769
progressBar_y_plus 780
progressBar_y_plus 794
progressBar_y_plus 803
progressBar_y_plus 815
progressBar_y_plus 822
progressBar_x_plus 1003
progressBar_y_plus 829
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_y_plus 836
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_y_plus 844
progressBar_x_plus 1004
progressBar_y_plus 850
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_y_plus 857
progressBar_x_plus 1004
progressBar_y_plus 865
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_y_plus 872
progressBar_x_plus 1006
progressBar_y_plus 880
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_y_plus 884
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_y_plus 893
progressBar_x_plus 1003
progressBar_y_plus 899
progressBar_x_plus 1003
progressBar_y_plus 905
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_y_plus 907
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_y_plus 913
progressBar_x_plus 1001
progressBar_y_plus 918
progressBar_x_plus 1004
progressBar_y_plus 924
progressBar_x_plus 1001
progressBar_y_plus 927
progressBar_y_plus 931
progressBar_x_plus 1003
progressBar_y_plus 938
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_y_plus 941
progressBar_x_plus 1002
progressBar_y_plus 945
progressBar_x_plus 1004
```

**Reason 1.**
I assume that progressBar counts 1000 as 100%.so `990 ~ 999` are counted as 99%.
To stop at 99%, this often happens mousemoving get slower than before ( because the mouse point the edge of screen.) We can reach 100% very soon sometimes.

**Reason 2.**

You update `new_x`, `new_y` to `self.old_x`, `self.old_y`, so the valuables almost equal to each other.It seems to go up to 100 from 99 easily.For the most part, we can reach 100% soon.But the fact is not always so.Because even if you plus `990 + 11` , even if the point is more than 1000, the progress bar doesn't become 100%... **This is the core reason to stop at 99%.**

For the evidence, you write `_update_bar`,for example, new_value = 900 + 11 , any number you like but it must be more than 1000 as the result.Your progress bars absolutely don't become full.Rather, they don't move at all.

```
progressBar_y_minus 992
109 132
progressBar_y_minus 1012
98 121
```

I would you like to move mouse slowly.You can see you reach 100% easier than you move mouse faster.Because the problem was the movement width of 9** ~ 1000.

If you move the mouse faster, the self._pos_x and event.pos().x() will make a big width.For this, it results in not being able to reach 100% vice versa.

So If I move the mouse from the left position of my pc window to right position of it very fast,the progress bar doesn't increase at all.If you are at 99%, the effect appears clearly.

When you circle the moving of mouse, you often see 99%.
But I think if you do it slowly, you can reach 100% with no problem.
circling contains all direction moving.It is not for one progressbar.
Until one moving ends, the next sometimes doesn't increase.
I assume that circling makes the width little by little, it is easier to reach 99% than other moving.
**fake news.**

It is not related with the desktop size.

**2.How can the code be fixed so that no QProgessBar takes a break at 99% ?**

If you understand the explanation of 1, you can escape from stopping by this code.

please try to write this code in `_update_bar` y punto...

```
if new_value > 1000:
   new_value = 1000
```

Comment: Your fix works very well, but I don't really understand it. Why is the screen size relevant for mouse movements in circles?

Comment: @Atalanttore It was things I forgot to delete, you are right.I reeditted.

Comment: Great, but I don't fully understand your explanation about the reason. Can you describe it more easily?

Comment: @Atalanttore Yes, I endevour to do it.Please give me some time.Sooner or later, I'm going to reedit in a week.